# Mysql, What is the correct way to nest EXISTS statements

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to put `EXISTS` statement inside an `EXISTS` statement , My version is not working.
Is it possible?

```
SELECT SUM(nbview) AS num_rows 
FROM `Release_link` 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id 
                 FROM Release 
                 WHERE Release.id = Release_link.release_id 
                   AND EXISTS (SELECT id 
                                 FROM Article 
                                WHERE Article.id = Release.article_id 
                                  AND Article.type = 'lol'));
```

Thanks to Jorge Campo for the solution ;) forg0t to quote something ;)

Comment: I did and it's not working ahah phpmyadmin return :  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Release WHERE Release.id = Release_link.release_id AND EXISTS (SELECT id FROM Ar' at line 1

Comment: you quoted Release_link on the first select... quote on the exists select also

Comment: ahaha wow thank you ;) it works now :) if I didn't quoted the first select, would it have worked? Also, is it the best way to get the best performance

Comment: from performance perspective, Depends on the tables relationsship, it would be much preferable to use a `JOIN` and not inner querries.

Comment: I see but using this I get  0.0003 sec while using Select SUM(rl.`nbview`) AS num_rows FROM `Release_link` rl INNER JOIN `Release` r ON r.`id` = rl.`release_id` INNER JOIN `Article` a ON (a.`id` = r.`article_id` AND a.`type` = 'lol') I get about the same performance... Well my database is still young but which one will be better... If I use left join, it will return more entry then I want...

Comment: @cloud1250000 It you didn't quote the first select, yes it would work either you quote or not, you have to follow the same quotes every time. About performance It depends on your table structure and your indexes. But usually a JOIN operation will be faster than EXISTS, for this specific case.

Comment: I Put as an answer so that can help other with the same issue. If it fits to you, consider in accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you quoted `Release_link` on the first `select` and did not quoted it on the first sub-select. Either you quote then both or none.

```
SELECT SUM(nbview) AS num_rows 
  FROM `Release_link` 
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id 
                 FROM Release 
                 WHERE Release.id = `Release_link`.release_id 
                   AND EXISTS (SELECT id 
                                 FROM Article 
                                WHERE Article.id = Release.article_id 
                                  AND Article.type = 'lol'));
```

Or

```
SELECT SUM(nbview) AS num_rows 
  FROM Release_link 
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id 
                 FROM Release 
                 WHERE Release.id = Release_link.release_id 
                   AND EXISTS (SELECT id 
                                 FROM Article 
                                WHERE Article.id = Release.article_id 
                                  AND Article.type = 'lol'));
```

Also for performance issues, on this especific case, prefer to use `INNER JOIN` operation. The Mysql engine will work better with the indexes (assuming that there are indexes on those IDs fields.)

```
SELECT SUM(Release_link.nbview) AS num_rows 
  FROM Release_link 
       INNER JOIN Release
          ON (Release.id = Release_link.release_id)
       INNER JOIN Article
          ON (Article.id = Release.article_id)
 WHERE Article.type = 'lol';
```

Comment: Thank you jorge for your time :)